# HTML with youtube video on iPhone - "Youtube not available"

Tags: iphone, html, youtube

I have a small website for mobile devices. It contains only a menu, some text and an embeded youtube video. I used this code for embeding: http://learningtheworld.eu/2009/youtube-embed/
When I click on the video on iPhone, the youtube app starts(thats fine), but I get the following error message: "Youtube not available". Could somebody help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. There was a privilege error on youtube. So the code is ok.
I write the problem, maybe it's useful: if you upload a video to youtube and set it to private and publish later, it won't work on iPad(however it's public), so you have to publish it immediately. I don't know why, but I did the same and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `embed` tag, try something like this:

```
<object width="480" height="360">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/VideoID"></param>
  <param name="autoplay" value="1">
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/VideoID&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" ></embed>
</object>
```